# Установка 404 ответа

Tags: php, nginx

сайт лежит на NGINX, написан на PHP.
На данный момент если обращаться к сайту по адресу
site/catalog/price.html отдает код 200
При обращение
site/price.html также отдает код 200

Вопрос, как нужно настроить сервер и прописать правила, чтобы дублирующая страница site/price.html отдавала код 404 , а все страницы с /catalog/ отдавали код 200.?

Также на сайте есть страницы без /catalog/ , например ru/shops, главное чтобы эти страницы не отдавали 404.

Comment: А почему при запросе site/price.html у вас идет ответ 200? У вас две копии price.html, настроен mod_rewrite (или как он там в nginx называется) или что-то еще?

Comment: Нужно исправлять не последствия, а причину почему у вас дублирующая страница отдает 200 а не 404

Comment: Согласен, в этом и вопрос, как это могло произойти? История такая раньше структура была без /catalog/ , после с /catalog/ , после анализа сайта я обнаружил, что обе версии доступны и понял, что ошибка настройки сервера, но куда копать точнее решил спросить здесь.